# Make font smaller with span item

Tags: css

I want to have a smaller font for "Konfuzius" here: http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/index.html

I tried to add a `span` around "Konfuzius" with the smaller font definition but somehow it does not work...
Here is the CSS file: http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/css/screen/screen-PAGE-layout.css

Comment: Please update your question with only the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `font-size` for the class `quote-author`. As `100%` `font-size` of any inherited `font-size` which is even though higher than `100%`, but `100%` shall render the same size irrespective of its inheritance being higher than that. So you need to reduce `quote-author` class to a value < `100%` to your convenient small-size in order to make it smaller.

**For Instance,**

```
.quote-author {
    font-size: 50%;
}
```

*PS: 50% value is just for illustrative purposes.*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have worked out how to do it because the css was changing every time I reloaded, but the answer as I think you have found is to use

```
.quote-author {
    font-size: Xpx; /*You can also use x%*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `font-size:100%` it represents 100% of the size in its parent (180%) so you don't change anything.
You should use something like `font-size:50%;` or whatever size you want specified in px...